# django inclusion_tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to create inclusion tag and place it on the page but it's not work.

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django import template


register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('weather.html')
def weather():
    return {'city': 'angola'}


def home(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')
```

index.html

```
<title> TITLE </title>

Hi everyone!

{% weather %}
```

weather.html

```
weather is fine in {{city}}
```

Django debug page says that "Invalid block tag: 'weather'" so I guess I put declaration of inclusion_tag in wrong place? Where I need to put it to get it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Template tags need to go in a module in your app's `templatetags` directory. See the code layout section of the custom [template tag docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for full details.

You then have to `load` your tag library in the template before you use your tag.

```
{% load my_tags %}
{% weather %}
```